# effective frame rate of the latest version of the Kinect camera, at high resolution and including infrared depth data?

Tags: kinect

What is the effective frame rate of the latest version of the Kinect camera, at high resolution and including highest resolution infrared depth data? I have read that it is actually only 9 fps. This seems at odds with other things I have seen online. Why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 9fps is achieved when using kinect fusion on the microsoft SDK, but on matlab it's close to 30 fps on the depth stream.